# How to get cover photo of album and photos of the album using FBGraph Api

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working with FBGraphAPI in my project. I managed to get the list of albums. I tried to get picutre (cover_photo) and photos in albums. But somehow i stuck in it.

Which inbuilt method i need to use to get cover_photo and photos in the album? And how to use it?

Comment: come in Chat... I am free now

Comment: @iProgrammer i got a albums photo but i did not get album cover photo..i refers this link but it not work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the cover_photo, you need to use

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<id>/picture?type=album&access_token=<token>
```

where id is the cover_photo from your album returned in the album list.
and token is your current session token

Note. It needs to be https and you need to specify the token. This is what makes it different than, for example, rendering a user's photo.

By photos in album, not sure if you mean the list of photos or the actual photo itself?
The basic process is to use the id of the album returned and then call

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<id>/photos
```

This will return a list of photos in the album. 
Within this list will be 'source' which contains the url of the photo. 
Also a dictionary of different photo resolutions.

Comment: The url you has given for coverphoto works fine. but the problem is when i create request using FBGraphAPI it says like input is nil, I do not understand this.

Comment: How are you forming the request? Have you tried entering the request in this tool? http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: Problem is solved. Actually my network administrator has blocked me from getting cover_photo urls. So because of that my array was showing me null.

Comment: What if i want actual photos of album.

Comment: how to get img with size 143 ?